# Apache beam word count example with spark runner fails with " Unknown 'runner' specified 'SparkRunner'"

Tags: apache-spark, apache-beam

I am trying to do spark-submit of the Apache beam word-count example by giving the below command

```
spark-submit --class org.apache.beam.examples.WordCount word-count-beam-0.1.jar --inputFile=pom.xml --output=counts --runner=SparkRunner
```

I get the below Exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown
>   'runner' specified 'SparkRunner', supported pipeline runners
>   [DirectRunner]

Answer (score 1):

Your pom.xml needs to include a dependency on the Spark runner. The documentation on using the [Spark runner](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/spark/) includes more details about what is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're not building an Uber-jar with the necessary Spark dependencies.
Re-run your Maven package as follows:

`mvn package -Pspark-runner`

This will build a Jar in `target` containing the `wordcount` classes as well as all of the necessary spark dependencies called something like:

`word-count-beam-bundled-0.1.jar`

Then use that jar in the `spark-submit` command